# close mongodb service in nodejs server close or error

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am writing the MongoDB trigger in nodejs using change stram functionality. I want to make it bulletproof. currently facing the issue if nodejs server is down with any reason like any error or genuinely. then my MongoDB database won't available or would be stopped. so, my data won't be messed up.

To fix, this issue I think to stop MongoDB service on nodejs trigger stopped (but how that I don't know). If you have any other solution you can share.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need capability to resume the change streams. Bascially every time you get a change, you also get a resume token id which can be provided to mongo while opening change stream so that it knows from where to start sending the changes. You could read more [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/#resume-a-change-stream)

There is another [article](https://medium.com/@montumodi/power-of-mongodb-change-streams-6e050ef3c499) which explains it with code example using nodejs.

Comment: this one is helpful. can anyone give me any other solution?